# sqlite get single row problems

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-studio

I have a problem for getting single row from sqlite database using android studio. When I run the apps on my device it run smoothly but when I type keyword and click the search button the apps force closed.

This is my dbhelper file:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hunterdb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public UserDbHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "Database created / opened...");
    }

    public Cursor getContact(String nopol, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        String[] projections= {UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_TYPE, UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_RANGKA, UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_MESIN, UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_BIAYA};
        String selection = UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_NOPOL+" LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args={nopol};
        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    }
}
```

and this is my searchcontactactivity class

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class SearchContantActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    TextView Display_nopol,Display_type,Display_rangka,Display_mesin,Display_pembiayaan;
    EditText Search_name;
    UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    String search_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caridata_layout);
        Search_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_name);
        Display_nopol=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnopol);
        Display_type=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttype);
        Display_rangka=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtrangka);
        Display_mesin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmesin);
        Display_pembiayaan=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtbiaya);
    }

    public void SearchContant(View view){
        search_name=Search_name.getText().toString();
        userDbHelper=new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase=userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=userDbHelper.getContact(search_name, sqLiteDatabase);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.yelp);
            mp.start();
            String TYPE=cursor.getString(0);
            String RANGKA=cursor.getString(1);
            String MESIN=cursor.getString(2);
            String BIAYA=cursor.getString(3);
            Display_type.setText(TYPE);
            Display_rangka.setText(RANGKA);
            Display_mesin.setText(MESIN);
            Display_pembiayaan.setText(BIAYA);
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data Tidak Ditemukan!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have made same program with a 3-columns-table and it run fine. But when I try make another one using a table with more than 3 columns the apps force close. Anyone know the problems? Thanks before and sorry 4 my bad english!!

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the Android debugger to figure out what error message is being displayed when your application force closes? That should give you an indication of what line the error is happening on.

Comment: I have tried to debug it but my emulator didn't show anything but android text for over 30 minutes. That's why I only tested my app on my device. Any advice? thanks

Comment: You can debug from your device also if it is plugged into your computer and USB debugging is enabled. Run `adb logcat`from a console window to see the log (if `adb` is not in your PATH, you'll need to execute the command from your `platform-tools` directory)

Comment: Post the exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `logcat` output:

Look for any `error` messages that might help you to identify the problem.

Add the following code to `onCreate()` in `SearchContantActivity`

```
Log.d("SearchContactActivity", "onCreate called");
```

2. Make sure the columns are correct

Check the column names in `SQL`, match them to `database` and make the `Java` code match it also.

Retrieve the value of a column named for example `DATA_NOPOL`.

```
int nopolIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("DATA_NOPOL");
String nopol = cursor.getString(nopolIndex);
```

`getColumnIndex()` returns the index, `getString()` retrieves the value.

3. Check the number of `columns` returned:

The number of `columns` returned have to match the number of `columns` that you get in the code.

Use `getColumnCount()`:

```
int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
Log.d("SearchContactActivity", "Column count: " + columnCount);
```

4. Check `columns` `data` type

The `data` types returned by `SQL` has to match the `data` of the vars in the code.

Check the `data` using `getType()`

```
int nopolIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("DATA_NOPOL");
int nopolType = cursor.getType(nopolIndex);
Log.d("SearchContactActivity", "Data type of nopol: " + nopolType);
```

Print the `data` of `DATA_NOPOL` to the logcat, which will identify if there is a mismatch win the `data` of the vars.

5. Test with a query

This will help identify if the query or the code has a problem getting `data`.

Modify `projections` array in your `getContact()`

```
String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.DATA_TYPE};
```

6. Check null vals

You have to check for null vals getting `data`. If a column has a null val, and you try to retrieve it, it will cause an error.

Use `isNull()` that will return true if the val is null:

```
int nopolIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("DATA_NOPOL");
if (!cursor.isNull(nopolIndex)) {
    String nopol = cursor.getString(nopolIndex);
    // Do something with nopol
} else {
    // Handle null value
}
```

7. Try-Catch blocks

Use them to handle exceptions that will be thrown by the code. This will identify the ****exact**** location where the error is getting.

Use try-catch to handle any `exception`.

```
try {
    // Code that might throw an exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SearchContactActivity", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```